# Whats the best way to install Ubuntu on a Samsung Chromebook?

Tags: google-chrome, samsung, chromebook

I have been wondering what's the best way to install Ubuntu, on a Samsung Chromebook 2

Specification: Intel Celeron with 2GB of RAM and 16 GB of flash storage.

I am really not sure if that will be enough space for Ubuntu. I want to run my Linux games on here, then I realized it can't really do much. I am just a geek that wants to tinker with his hardware and operating system. And mostly because I want to use Ubuntu on the go, without using crouton. Even though it would void my warranty, but at the same time I don't want to brick my Chromebook since I just got it 2 weeks ago I somewhat enjoy Chrome os but I need my Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience, you won't be running a very stable system with Crouton, which is essentially what you are describing with your last sentence. You can either run a nicely configured ChromeOS installation, or a nice ChromeOS configuration with Crouton to preview what a Linux distribution would look like on a Chromebook.

If you want to run a stable Ubuntu distribution on your Chromebook, you will probably have to replace ChromeOS with Ubuntu.

You can see whether your Samsung Chromebook is supported by John Lewis' custom BIOS [here](https://johnlewis.ie/custom-chromebook-firmware/rom-download/).

If you think you would like to potentially risk bricking your device, you can proceed with the instructions [here.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Samsung_Chromebook_%28ARM%29)

I used the steps [here](http://paste.debian.net/415583/) for a dozen Dell Chromebooks but your instructions may differ because you are using Samsung.